# Node.js sqlite export database

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a problem with `node.js` and `node sqlite` npm package. I am making a server-client app and i need to interrogate a sqlite db a lot, and i observed when i do more than 4 queries at a request it is **beginning to block the event loop** when reading from file.

```
var data_db = new sqlite3.Database('data.db');
```

Sometimes i get even a 18 seconds event block. This happens when i do many requests on server, otherwise i get 40ms 50ms event block as well, which is not good.

I observed if o do it in the memory, everything goes lightning fast.

```
var data_db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
```

So my idea is to make everything in memory and at the beginning to import from `data.db` then at every 60 seconds to export it to `data.db`

The thing is that i don't know how to export from node.js, how do i do that? Ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution?